# I'm in USA with a F1 visa. Can I drive in the UK with my MA Driver's License?

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, driving-license, driving

I am in the USA on a F1 visa. I also have a MA Driver's License slash Real ID. I am visiting the UK later this month to attend a conference. A friend (in UK) advised I should get some additional paperwork that shows I am allowed to drive in the US with a F1 student visa. I am not quite sure what that means. Do I need to get additional paperwork? I have read on several places on the Internet stating that I should have no problem driving in the UK with my US license (provided that I am only there for a small number of days and do not intend to get a resident status). I am confused after my friend gave me the advise. What should I do?

Comment: You can use the tool on gov.uk to find out https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence If you’re planning to hire a car you could also check the T&C of the hire company; if you’re going to be driving eg a friend’s car then they should probably check their insurance allows this.

Comment: You have a Massachusetts driver's license.  This means that you are licensed to drive in the US.  Being *licensed* to drive in the US means that you are *allowed* to drive in the US.  That is the principal purpose of a driver's license and the reason why driver's licenses exist.  For what purpose does your friend think you would need "additional paperwork that shows [you are] allowed to drive in the US with a F1 student visa"?  What does that have to do with driving *in the UK* with that license?  Why would anyone in the UK care about -- or even know about -- your US immigration status?